# I am not able to create the XSLT for below problem

Tags: xml, xslt

I am not able to create the XSLT for below problem.

Max Amount = 100

Input:

```
EMP1
AMT = 10
EMP1
AMT = 20
EMP1 
AMT = 90
EMP2
AMT = 50
EMP2
AMT = 60
```

OUTPUT

```
Header

EMP1 
AMT = 10

EMP1
AMT = 20

EMP1
AMT = 20     ---  EMP1 Amount total exceeding max amount so Total amount - Max Amount and rest of the amount will go in next batch section 

Trailer
------------------------------

Header

EMP1
AMT = 70

EMP2
AMT = 50

EMP2 
AMT = 10

Trailer
------------------------------

Header

EMP2
AMT = 50  and so on according to the data

Trailer
```

No Batch record will contain the same employee whose sum of amount is exceeding max amount.

I tried using local and global variables and also tried Key concept in XSLT but nothing seems to be working. Help will be much appreciated.

Tried the scenario and capturing Amount field using local and global variable and also used Key functionality of xslt but no Luck

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:xp20="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/oracle.tip.pc.services.functions.Xpath20"
                xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="/DATA_DS/G_1/G_2/FILE_FRAGMENT/TEST_DD/Rel_Action">
            <xsl:variable name="Amount_MAX">100</xsl:variable>
            <!-- HEADER Begin -->
            <xsl:text>Header</xsl:text>
            <!-- HEADER End -->

            <!-- DETAIL Begin -->
            <xsl:for-each select="/DATA_DS/G_1/G_2/FILE_FRAGMENT/TEST_DD/Rel_Action">
              <xsl:variable name="Amount_Loop"
                  select="Personal_Payments_Trav/Personal_Payments/Personal_Payment_Rec/Payment_Amount"/>
                <xsl:choose>    
                    <xsl:when test="/DATA_DS/G_1/G_2/FILE_FRAGMENT/TEST_DD/Rel_Action/Personal_Payments_Trav/Personal_Payments/Personal_Payment_Rec/Payment_Amount &lt; 100">
                        <xsl:value-of select="Personal_Payments_Trav/Personal_Payments/Personal_Payment_Rec/Payment_Amount"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <Record>
                            <xsl:value-of select="Personal_Payments_Trav/Personal_Payments/Personal_Payment_Rec/Payment_Amount - 99"/>
                        </Record>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
                <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                <!--Single space filler-->
                <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <!-- DETAIL End -->

            <!-- TRAILER Begin -->
            <xsl:text>Trailer</xsl:text>
            <!-- TRAILER End -->
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

```
Header

EMP1 
AMT = 10

EMP1
AMT = 20

EMP1
AMT = 20     ---  EMP1 Amount total exceeding max amount so Total amount - Max Amount and rest of the amount will go in next batch section 

Trailer
------------------------------

Header

EMP1
AMT = 70

EMP2
AMT = 50

EMP2 
AMT = 10

Trailer
------------------------------

Header
```

Comment: Take it one step at a time but with any XSLT problem we need to see small, representative sample of the input you and want to transform together with the output you want and the one you get. It also helps if you tell us which version of XSLT and/or which XSLT processor you use, your code has `version="2.0"`, is that the version you can work with?

Comment: I don't understand the logic that needs to be applied here. Why is the first "batch" 10, 20, 20 and not 10, 20, 70?

Comment: For each employee which will be written in the batch the addition of the amount should not be greater then 100 so in my case Emp 1 total amount if exceeding 100 so I have written the 20 not 70 (90+20+10-100=20) and rest of the amount in next batch.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite a tricky problem in XSLT. If you can use xsl:iterate in XSLT 3.0, then I would suggest:

(a) first pass: use `xsl:iterate` to inject "new-batch" elements at the point where a new batch needs to start, which you can do by maintaining the size of the current batch as a parameter to `xsl:iterate`. When you find an item that needs to split across two (or more?) batches, then do the splitting in this pass.

(b) second pass: use `xsl:for-each-group group-starting-with="new-batch"` to generate output grouped by batch.

Sorry, I don't have time to work out the detail for you.

Comment: Sir please provide some more info as I am not familiar with this.

Comment: As I said, this isn't an easy problem; it would take me half-an-hour to work through a solution, and I don't have that amount of time available for answering SO questions. I've tried to point you in the right direction and indicate the topics you will need to learn about before you can tackle this kind of problem.